# How to use scala slick's codegen generate Tables from mysql's sql file?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have read slick's document and example project but also wonder how to use sql file to generation mysql scala code.
I'm use this way connect to mysql database and generate Tables

```
import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver

private object CodeGen extends App {
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb"
  val slickDriver = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile"
  val jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val outputFolder = "app/"

  SourceCodeGenerator.main(
    Array(
      slickDriver,
      jdbcDriver,
      url,
      outputFolder,
      "com.company.db.table",
      "myusername",
      "mypassword"
    )
  )
}
```

This way can generate all table form mydb database.
But how about use a sql file to generate a part of tables in mydb? Official examples use h2 db but not comment for mysql configration.

Thanks for any advice.